# Why isn't my unordered lists not being positioned beside the centered image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put my two lists beside the image that is centered in the middle one on each side but the two lists have to be centered and not all the way right or left.

Thanks in advance. 
*Please fullscreen the html snippet.

```css
div.main p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

div.main h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

div.material {
  float: left;
}

div.material h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.list li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

div.materialy {
  float: right;
}

div.materialy h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.listy li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

div.method p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.method li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

div.skill li {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div.skill p {
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F00;
}

div.image img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid black;
  border-top: solid black;
  border-left: solid black;
  border-right: solid black;
  background: #09F;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#09F, #9FF);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

div.nav li {
  float: left;
}

div.nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #0FC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="style4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<head>
  <title>Tips</title>
</head>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Tips</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Learn</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Welcome to the tips page!</h1>
    <p>
      <br>Artists typically use great techniques to make their art more professional looking and it also helps them improve their skills at drawing.
      <br>They use different types of mediums, tools, and art supplies to enhance the looks of their artwork.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="material">
    <h2>Materials for a beginner or newbie:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li>HB #2 Pencil</li>
        <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
        <li>White printer paper</li>
        <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="person-drawing.jpg" height="296" width="395"></div>
  <div class="materialy">
    <h2>Materials for the advanced:</h2>
    <div class="listy">
      <ul>
        <li>Staedtler Design/Drafting Pencil Set</li>
        <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
        <li>Gum eraser</li>
        <li>Kneaded eraser</li>
        <li>White printer paper</li>
        <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
        <li>Blending sticks</li>
        <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencils</li>
        <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencil lead</li>
        <li>Fine tip liner marker</li>
        <li>Adjustable drafting table</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="method">
    <p>Here are some good methods and techniques to practice drawing skills:</p>
    <ul>
      <div class="skill">
        <li>Drawing is a skill</li>
        <p>*Drawing isn't some magical activity that people are born with! It can be taught and learnt from also, anyone can be skilled at drawing!</p>
      </div>
      <li>Drawing or sketching lightly</li>
      <li>Observe your artwork while drawing regularly</li>
      <li>Look for basic shapes</li>
      <li>Take your time</li>
      <li>Use guidelines/structure to form the foundation of the drawing</li>
      <li>Use resources if needed</li>
      <li>Be consistent</li>
      <li>Relax and have fun</li>
      <li>Keep practicing constantly</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the rewritten code:
     https://jsfiddle.net/vsjka9r7/

```
<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Learn</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
<h1>Welcome to the tips page!</h1>
<p><br>
    Artists typically use great techniques to make their art more professional looking and it also helps them improve their skills at drawing.
<br>
    They use different types of mediums, tools, and art supplies to enhance the looks of their artwork.
</p>
</div>
<div class="centerContentController">
<div class="leftList">
    <div class="material">
        <h2>Materials for a beginner or newbie:</h2>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li>HB #2 Pencil</li>
            <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
            <li>White printer paper</li>
            <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="person-drawing.jpg" height="296" width="395" class="materialsImg">
 <div class="rightList">
    <div class="materialy">
        <h2>Materials for the advanced:</h2>
            <div class="listy">
                <ul>
                    <li>Staedtler Design/Drafting Pencil Set</li>
                    <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
                    <li>Gum eraser</li>
                    <li>Kneaded eraser</li>
                    <li>White printer paper</li>
                    <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
                    <li>Blending sticks</li>
                    <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencils</li>
                    <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencil lead</li>
                    <li>Fine tip liner marker</li>
                    <li>Adjustable drafting table</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <br>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bottomContent">
<div class="method">
    <p>Here are some good methods and techniques to practice drawing skills:
</p>
        <ul>
          <div class="skill">
              <li>Drawing is a skill</li>
              <p>*Drawing isn't some magical activity that people are born with! It can be taught and learnt from also, anyone can be skilled at drawing!</p>
          </div>
          <li>Drawing or sketching lightly</li>
          <li>Observe your artwork while drawing regularly</li>
          <li>Look for basic shapes</li>
          <li>Take your time</li>
          <li>Use guidelines/structure to form the foundation of the drawing</li>
          <li>Use resources if needed</li>
          <li>Be consistent</li>
          <li>Relax and have fun</li>
          <li>Keep practicing constantly</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Does that work for ya?
If not I am here to help :)

What I changed:
I simply created a div container to contain the image and the two unordered list.
I then created a div for each of the unordered list and floated them to the right/left. For the center image I positioned it in the center.

Comment: Please up vote the answer. I would like to get the student badge.

Comment: It does. Though I had to do a bit of tinkering and things to make things tidier.

Comment: I find theres a big gap between the top and bottom sides of the image. How do I make the gap smaller? @Seth

Comment: Please post a link to an image.

Comment: If you're looking for votes from others, consider explaining what you changed and *why*.

Comment: Also there is a gap between the "Materials for a beginner or newbie:" list for some odd positioning.

Comment: Also please up vote my comment, It will help me alot.

Comment: @LunarOblivion Send it in JS Fiddle

Comment: @SethJ.Freeman Ok I fixed it, thanks. http://imgur.com/a/DcS5z is there a way to make the gap spacing smaller?

Comment: @LunarOblivion msg was too long to post here: https://pastebin.com/750f1Mqv

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to put all DIV tags inside BODY. Then you have to clean up a little your DIVs. In order not to rewrite the whole HTML code, I would suggest you to use a table for the lists:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="style4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<head>
  <title>Tips</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Tips</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Learn</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>Welcome to the tips page!</h1>
    <p>
      <br>Artists typically use great techniques to make their art more professional looking and it also helps them improve their skills at drawing.
      <br>They use different types of mediums, tools, and art supplies to enhance the looks of their artwork.</p>
  </div>

  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td align="center" width="33%">
    <div class="material">
        <h2>Materials for a beginner or newbie:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
        <li>HB #2 Pencil</li>
        <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
        <li>White printer paper</li>
        <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
   <td align="center" width="33%">
    <div class="image">
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>
        <img src="person-drawing.jpg" height="296" width="395">
    </div>  
  </td> 
   <td align="center" width="33%">
      <div class="materialy">
        <h2>Materials for the advanced:</h2>
        <div class="listy">
          <ul>
            <li>Staedtler Design/Drafting Pencil Set</li>
            <li>Clean white vinyl eraser</li>
            <li>Gum eraser</li>
            <li>Kneaded eraser</li>
            <li>White printer paper</li>
            <li>Good lighting or desk lamp</li>
            <li>Blending sticks</li>
            <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencils</li>
            <li>0.5/0.7 mechanical pencil lead</li>
            <li>Fine tip liner marker</li>
            <li>Adjustable drafting table</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </td> 
  </tr>
  </table>

  </br>
  <div class="method">
    <p>Here are some good methods and techniques to practice drawing skills:</p>
    <ul>
      <div class="skill">
        <li>Drawing is a skill</li>
        <p>*Drawing isn't some magical activity that people are born with! It can be taught and learnt from also, anyone can be skilled at drawing!</p>
      </div>
      <li>Drawing or sketching lightly</li>
      <li>Observe your artwork while drawing regularly</li>
      <li>Look for basic shapes</li>
      <li>Take your time</li>
      <li>Use guidelines/structure to form the foundation of the drawing</li>
      <li>Use resources if needed</li>
      <li>Be consistent</li>
      <li>Relax and have fun</li>
      <li>Keep practicing constantly</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just add width="100%" to the table tag and things will be displayed correctly.